# Evaluate $\int \frac{\sqrt{64x^2-256}}{x}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

**QUESTION**

> Evaluate $$\int \frac{\sqrt{64x^2-256}}{x}\,dx$$

I've tried this problem multiple times and cant seem to find where I made a mistake. If someone could please help explain where I went wrong I would really appreciate it

**MY ATTEMPT**

- Typed

> $\newcommand{\dd}{\; \mathrm{d}}\int \frac{\sqrt{64x^2-256}}x \dd x \to 
> \int \frac{\sqrt{64(x^2-4)}}x \dd x \to
> \int \frac{8\sqrt{x^2-4}}x \dd x$
>
> Use $x=a\sec\theta$, $\dd x=a\sec\theta \tan\theta \dd \theta$.
>
> $a=2$ $\to$ $x=2\sec\theta$, $\dd x=2\sec\theta \tan\theta \dd \theta$.
>
> $=\int \frac{8\sqrt{4\sec^2\theta-4}}{2\sec\theta}(2\sec\theta\tan\theta) \dd \theta \to
> \int \frac{8\sqrt{4(\sec^2\theta-1)}}{2\sec\theta}(2\sec\theta\tan\theta) \dd \theta $
>
> $=\int \frac{8\sqrt{4\tan^2\theta}}{2\sec\theta}(2\sec\theta\tan\theta) \dd \theta \to
> \int \frac{8(2\tan\theta)}{2\sec\theta}(2\sec\theta\tan\theta) \dd \theta$
>
> $=\int 16\tan^2\theta \dd \theta \to
> 16\int\tan^2\theta \dd \theta \to
> \underset{\text{trig. formula}}{\underbrace{16(\theta+\tan\theta)+C}}$
>
> $\Rightarrow 16(\tan\theta-\theta)+C = 16\tan\theta-16\theta$
>
> $x=2\sec\theta$, $\sec\theta= \frac x2$
>
> $\boxed{16\tan\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}2\right) -16\sec^{-1}\left(\frac x2\right)+C}$

- Handwritten

[image]

Comment: Poor quality images of handwritten work are usually received poorly on Math SE. Try to type up all your work in your posts. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The substitution $x=\frac{2}{\sin\theta}$ gives an easy integral.

Comment: I have tried to edit your attempt based on the images you posted. This should make it easier for you to edit it further into the form which really reflects what you want to say.

Answer (score 7):

Since I am almost blind, I have a lot of problems reading the image.

Consider $$I=\int \frac{\sqrt{64 x^2-256}}{x}\,dx$$ What you apparently did is $x=2\sec(t)$, $dx=2 \tan (t) \sec (t)$ which make $$I=\int \tan (t) \sqrt{256 \sec ^2(t)-256}\,dt=16\int \tan (t) \sqrt{\tan ^2(t)}\,dt=16\int \tan^2 (t) \,dt$$ $$I=16\int (1+\tan^2(t)-1)\,dt=16 (\tan (t)-t)$$

Comment: Hi i did this and found t to equal arcsec(x/2) but when I plugged this into the equation it says that the answer isn't correct.

Comment: If you properly replace $t$, you should arrive to $2 \sqrt{x^2-64}+16 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{8}{\sqrt{x^2-64}}\right)$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With the
>   sub$\ds{\ldots\ t \equiv x - \root{x^{2} - 4}\ \imp\
> x = {t^{2} + 4 \over 2t}}$:

---

\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\int{\root{64x^{2} - 256} \over x}\,\dd x} =
8\int{\root{x^{2} - 4} \over x}\,\dd x =
8\int\pars{{8 \over t^{2} + 4} - {16 \over t^{2}} + 3}\,\dd t
\\[3mm] = &\
32\arctan\pars{t \over 2} + {128 \over t} + 24t
\\[3mm] = &\ 
32\arctan\pars{x - \root{x^{2} - 4} \over 2} + {128 \over x - \root{x^{2} - 4}} + 24\pars{x - \root{x^{2} - 4}}
\\[3mm] = &\
32\arctan\pars{x - \root{x^{2} - 4} \over 2} +
32\pars{x + \root{x^{2} - 4}} + 24\pars{x - \root{x^{2} - 4}}
\\[3mm] = &\
\color{#f00}{32\arctan\pars{x - \root{x^{2} - 4} \over 2} +
56x + 8\root{x^{2} - 4}} + \pars{~\mbox{a constant}~}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{\sqrt{64x^2-256}}x=8x\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x^2}$$

Let $\sqrt{x^2-4}=y\implies x^2-4=y^2\implies x\ dx= y\ dy$

$$\int\dfrac{\sqrt{64x^2-256}}xdx=8\int\dfrac{y^2dy}{y^2+4}=8\int dy-32\int\dfrac{dy}{y^2+4}=?$$

Comment: @user376343,Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
&\int \frac{\sqrt{64x^2-256}}{x}\,dx\\
 =& \int \bigg( \frac{8x}{\sqrt{{x^2}-4}}-\frac{32}{x^2\sqrt{1-\frac4{x^2}}}\bigg)\,dx
=\ 8 \sqrt{{x^2}-4}+16\sin^{-1}\frac2x
\end{align}